# Apache 2.4 redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect everyone to a maintenance page except for my static IP.  In my sites directory I have the .htaccess file with xx being my ip

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xx.xxx.xxx.xx
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

But when i visit from another location I get

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

In my sites virtual host I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin server@admin.com
     ServerName something.com
     ServerAlias www.something.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/something.com/public_html/
     ErrorLog /var/www/something.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/something.com/logs/access.log combined
     <Directory /var/www/something.com/public_html/>
         Require all granted
         AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any ideas how to stop the redirect loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a redirect loop since you're unconditionally redirecting to `maintenance.html`.

To prevent redirect loop use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xx.xxx.xxx.xx
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.html$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L,NC]
```

Which means don't redirect if your request is already `maintenance.html`.